# How to properly set up mock Request.Form in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, nunit

I'm trying to create an HttpContextAccessor mock class for use in my controller unit tests.  I have this so far.

```
public class MockHttpContextAccessor
{
    public Mock<IHttpContextAccessor> ContextAccessor { get; private set; }
    public FormCollection RequestForm { get; private set; }
    private FormFileCollection fileCollection;
    
    public MockHttpContextAccessor()
    {
        var requestFeature = new HttpRequestFeature();
        var features = new FeatureCollection();

        features.Set<IHttpRequestFeature>(requestFeature);
        ContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        var session = new MockHttpSession();
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext(features);

        fileCollection = new FormFileCollection();
        RequestForm = new FormCollection(new Dictionary<string, StringValues>(), fileCollection);
        
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(context);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Session).Returns(session);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Path).Returns("/path");
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Form).Returns(RequestForm);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files).Returns(RequestForm.Files);
        ContextAccessor.Setup(x => x.HttpContext.Request.Headers).Returns(new Mock<IHeaderDictionary>().Object);
    }

    public void AddFormFieldsOrFile(Dictionary<string, StringValues> fields, List<IFormFile> files = null)
    {
        if (files != null && files.Any())
        {
            ContextAccessor.Object.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
            fileCollection.AddRange(files);
        }

        RequestForm = new FormCollection(fields, fileCollection);
    }
}

public class MockHttpSession : ISession
{
    Dictionary<string, object> sessionStorage = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get { return sessionStorage[name]; }
        set { sessionStorage[name] = value; }
    }

    string ISession.Id
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    bool ISession.IsAvailable
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    IEnumerable<string> ISession.Keys
    {
        get { return sessionStorage.Keys; }
    }

    void ISession.Clear()
    {
        sessionStorage.Clear();
    }

    void ISession.Remove(string key)
    {
        sessionStorage.Remove(key);
    }

    void ISession.Set(string key, byte[] value)
    {
        sessionStorage[key] = value;
    }

    public Task LoadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task CommitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    bool ISession.TryGetValue(string key, out byte[] value)
    {
        object storageValue = null;
        if(sessionStorage.TryGetValue(key, out storageValue))
        {
            var bytes = storageValue as byte[];

            if(bytes != null)
            {
                value = bytes;
                return true;
            }

            value = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(storageValue.ToString());
            return true;
        }

        value = null;
        return false;
    }        
}
```

Most of it is working fine.  However, if I try to access Request.Form for values, the Keys property on it is null, BUT, the Files property is set correctly and has one file.  In my test setup, this is the code that I'm calling to set the form values and file.

```
var content = "This is a test file";
var fileName = "test.pdf";
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
writer.Write(content);
writer.Flush();
stream.Position = 0;
IFormFile file = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, "field_id", fileName);

var formContents = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>()
{
    {"attachment-id", "1"},
    {"prelim", "false"}
};

_httpContextAccessor.AddFormFieldsOrFile(formContents, new List<IFormFile>{ file });
```